# python incorrectly calculates number

Tags: python, python-3.5

So, this was in my exam paper and I was really confused

```
def num_input():
    num1 = input("num1: ")
    num2 = input("num2: ")
    num1 = int(num2)*2.5
    num2 = int(num1)*1.5
    print("num1:", num1, "num2:", num2)

num_input()
```

say that num1 = 60, and num2 = 18, shouldn't the new numbers be:

```
num1: 45
num2: 90
```

but why is the output:

```
num1: 45
num2: 67.5
```

?

Comment: I bet "python **correctly** calculates number"...

Comment: Because you've assigned the result of `18 * 2.5` to num1, then converting to int and multiplying the result by 1.5 and assigning to num2. In other words the first input value is ignored.

Comment: @EcirHana hahaha, yeah after i read the answer it finally makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you calculate

```
num1 = int(num2)*2.5
```

the value of 'int(num2)*2.5' is assigned to num1. At this stage, num1 has a new value which is the evaluation of the above result and its not 60 anymore.

Change your code to this instead:

```
def num_input():
    num1 = input("num1: ")
    num2 = input("num2: ")
    value1 = int(num2)*2.5
    value2 = int(num1)*1.5
    print("num1:", value1, "num2:", value2)

num_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    num1 = input("num1: ")  # 60
    num2 = input("num2: ")  # 18
    num1 = int(num2)*2.5  # 18 * 2.5 = 45
    num2 = int(num1)*1.5  # 45 * 1.5 = 67.5
 `  print("num1:", num1, "num2:", num2)
```

## In comment lines, answer is calculated

Answer (score 1):

You can use in-place swapping to resolve this:

```
def num_input():
    num1 = input("num1: ")
    num2 = input("num2: ")
    num1,num2 = int(num2)*2.5, int(num1)*1.5
    print("num1:", num1, "num2:", num2)

>>>num_input()
num1: 60
num2: 18
('num1:', 45.0, 'num2:', 90.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

in num2 you are multipliying the result of num1 after the math operations instead of doing it before, when you write "num1 =" you are assigning a new value inside the "num1" variable memory position.

Comment: ah so that's why! thank you!